# Cuda Programming in comparision with C Programming

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing

I am new to cuda programming. I have few problems in understanding the cuda code. I am going through the cuda tutorial from this link : [cuda - tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/wiki/TutorialGlobalFunctions)

Basically, in that they are trying to pass an array to a function and assign `7` to each index of that array. In C we would typically do it using a for loop

```
  for(int index = 0; index < num_elements; ++index)
  {
    array[index] = 7;
  }
```

In CUDA the tutorial says it is done this way :

```
__global__ void kernel(int *array)
{
  int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  array[index] = 7;
}
```

It says that the line `int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;` is similar to the for loop written in c except that for is sequential and in cuda its done parallelly. I did not understand how the parallel processing is done by this `int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;` Can some one explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to cuda programming.

Say your grid has 10 blocks, each block having 64 threads. For each thread:

- `blockIdx.x` tells the id of the block the calling thread belongs to.
- `blockDim.x` is 64.
- `threadIdx.x` tells the id of the calling thread
  within its belonging block.

Now what we often want to have is the *global thread id within the entire grid*, and `int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;` is how we get it.

Answer (score 1):

In the CUDA code somewhere there should be a call to kernel looking something like this:

```
kernel <<< gridDim, blockDim >>> (array);
```

This is the line that makes the kernel parallel. `gridDim` and `blockDim` are used to tell the GPU how many threads are launched.

Each launched thread can then be thought of as calling the `__global__` function. The variables `blockIdx.x`, `blockDim.x` and `threadIdx.x` allow you to calculate a unique index per thread.

Comment: Why is it blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ? and not anything else? What does it mean when the blockId is multiplied with the blockDim and added to threadId

Comment: A grid is partitioned into a block, and each block is partitioned into threads. The `threadIdx` is unique within a block, the `blockIdx` is unique within a gird. In 1D (as your case is) each thread can have a threadIdx.x from 0->`blockDim.x`. To ensure a unique `index` the second block (ie. `blockIdx.x == 1`) needs to offset the index by `blockDim.x`, giving an `index` of `blockDim.x`->`2*blockDim.x`.